# In Informatica How to Handle nulls coming from SQL Query and Replace the same length of Column Space in Flat Files

Tags: sql, informatica, iics

For example I have SQL data like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
-----------------------
0010    01P98   UA500
0010    NULL    UA500
```

I need output in a flat file like this:

[image]

But I am getting output as below if I use `isnull`, `is_Spaces`, `ReplaceString` etc. functions.

[image]

Please suggest some code in Informatica.

Comment: Have you looked at `coalesce()`?

Comment: Yes i did, it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `lpad` along with isnull() check.

```
lpad(IIF(isnull(col2),'',col2),' ',5)
```

This will pad with 5 spaces if its null and if its not null, then it will simply left pad spaces until col2 length is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Although Koushik's answer will work just fine, in fact you should define your output as a fixed-width file and let Informatica do the job.

Once the target is a fixed-width file with proper pors length definition, Informatica will pad the values for all ports appropriately and there will be no LPAD functions required for any of the output ports.